# Extract Saved Word Document inside OneNote Notebook on OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Office 2013, saving documents on <strike>Sky</strike>OneDrive is fully integrated into Word.  On a computer using Word 2013, I wrote a document and saved it into a folder in my OneDrive.

When I went to a computer with Office 2010, I logged into the OneDrive web interface, intending to go to that document and click "Open in Word" to continue editing it.  However, I was unable to find the document.

After some thought and investigation, I realized that the "folder" in which I had saved the document wasn't a folder at all - it was actually a OneNote notebook!  However, opening that OneNote notebook, both in the OneDrive web interface and in the OneNote desktop application shows no sign of the Word document.  The only hint that the document is there is the following message in the Notebook properties: "This notebook also contains sections in other formats" - when, in fact, the notebook actually only has one section.

[image: This notebook also contains sections in other formats]

Is there some way I can get this document out without having to go back to Office 2013 on another computer and moving it?

---

P. S.  It would be really great if anyone here knows someone in the Office or OneDrive product groups at Microsoft and lets them know that this has to be fixed.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I'm running into this now, and it's driving me mad. The only way I can get at these docs, is to open each one individually in Word 2013 (mine are all Word docs and I have a lot of them), and save as to a different location.

Comment: @G_P no, I haven't found a better way.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: I think that if you sync the folder containing the notebook to a computer using the onedrive client, you will be able to remove it and OneNote will sort itself out.

You cannot do this in the web interface since that automatically starts the OneNote.com interface on the folder containing the notebook.

If you want help from Microsoft for this consumer service, you should use the feedback feature. Alternatvely, try one of the forums:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home
- https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home

---

Perhaps you saved the document to the folder that contains the notebook? If so, it wouldn't appear in the OnceNote notebook itself as the processing only works one way. That is to say that if you add the document into the notebook using the OneNote client, it DOES go into the OS folder but putting something direct into the folder will not make it appear in the OneNote interface.

If this is the case, simply navigate to the OS folder using Windows explorer. Any notebook that you've opened in the OneNote client is cached to your PC. So find the folder on your PC and hopefully you will find the document file. Drag it somewhere convenient.

Note that OneNote notebooks are actually a collection of folders and files (compressed XML). When stored on a network drive such as SharePoint or OneDrive or a shared drive, they are cached locally and synchronised as needed.

Comment: Yes, I *know* that I saved the document in the Notebook folder - I said that in the question.  My question was "is there a way to get into that folder **from the OneDrive *Web* interface?**  I fully understand the nature of OneNote's format as a collection of folders and files - the problem here is that Windows see them as "real" folders but OneDrive does not!

Comment: Additionally, you answered about how to "recover" the file from the OneNote cache on my computer.  That's not my problem - I can get to the file just fine *on my computer* through Word 2013 because Word sees the OneNote Notebook as a *regular folder*. I am asking about downloading the file *from the **OneDrive** web interface*.